# flutter widget_test cannot find _MyAppState Class and the class static variable

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing

I am doing a Flutter unit test on myAppState variable mytasks index to be non-zero.

Issue: widget_test file cannot find _MyAppState class and the class static variable tasks from the lib folder.

widget_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dk_phila_1/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  bool x=false;

  testWidgets('non-zero id', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    if(_MyAppState.tasks[index].id!=0) {
      x = _MyAppState.tasks[index].id > 0;
    }
    expect(x,true);
    await tester.pump();
  });
}
```

main.dart:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> 
  static final List<Task> tasks=<Task>[];
```

Please advise how to address the issue. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Underscore (_) at beginning of class name simply means that this is a private class and it is not visible outside this file. So, if you really want to test this class, you need to remove underscore (it will make state public). So, you can try this:

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> 
  static final List<Task> tasks=<Task>[];
```

In general, you should avoid testing private things anywhere. Good practice is to invoke public methods/APIs in unit tests and make assertions/verifications on results/mocks/stubs.

Comment: Hello! The _ClassName works fine within lib folder for all files. The problem occurs using test folder where widget_test.dart is found. I will try your suggestion. Thank You